# Create a filestream and saving it

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I'm new to this forum and I'm wondering if I could get some help regarding a filestream in Visual Basic 2015.

I'm trying to read a file and editing some values in it on binary level. Currently I got the following code:

```
Dim fStream4 As New FileStream(FirmwareFileLocation.Remove(FileLocation.Length - 3) + "_tmp_final.dd", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
Dim br4 As New BinaryWriter(fStream4)

br4.Write(final2bytes)
br4.Close()
fStream4.Close()
```

The problem is that I am not getting a new file when I'm hitting the button to execute this part of the code. Am I forgetting something or is something going wrong here?

Please note, I'm new to using filestreams so my knowledge is very limited. All I know are some of the very basics that I've read about.

Update:

```
Private Sub SaveDataButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveDataButton.Click
    '     Dim Writer As New BinaryWriter(File.Open("C:/test.bin", FileMode.Create))
    '    Dim numBytes As Long = tempArr.Length
    '   Writer.Write("R")
    '  Writer.Write(456)
    ' Writer.Write(456.789)
    ' Writer.Write("please test string here")


    '   Dim fStream As New FileStream(LocationOfFirmware.FileName + "_tmp_new", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write)
    '   Dim br As New BinaryWriter(fStream)

    '   tempArr = br.Write(CInt(numBytes))


    Dim newbytes() As Byte = TempArr2
    Dim newstring = UnicodeBytesToString(newbytes)


    '     CurrentArticleTextBox.Text = Mid(string2, 1652, 19)

    Dim temparr5 = NewSerialNumber.Text

    Dim SerialNumberOffset As Integer = 1625 ' Offset van het serienummer in de gemodificeerde array (1625, 11 bytes)
    Dim ArticleNumberOffset As Integer = 1643 ' Offset van het artikelnummer in de gemodificeerde array (1643, 19 bytes)


    Dim MacAddress1Offset As Integer = 1676 ' Offset van MAC Adres #1 in de gemodificeerde array (1676, 17 bytes)
    Dim MacAddress2Offset As Integer = 2014 ' Offset van MAC Adres #2 in de gemodificeerde array (2014, 17 bytes)
    Dim MacAddress3Offset As Integer = 2088 ' Offset van MAC Adres #3 in de gemodificeerde array (2088, 17 bytes)
    Dim MacAddress4Offset As Integer = 2155 ' Offset van MAC Adres #4 in de gemodificeerde array (2155, 17 bytes)


    ' Nieuw serienummer
    For i = SerialNumberOffset To SerialNumberOffset + 10
        newbytes(i) = AscW(NewSerialNumber.Text(i - SerialNumberOffset))
    Next

    '' Nieuw artiekelnummer
    For i = ArticleNumberOffset To ArticleNumberOffset + 18
        newbytes(i) = AscW(NewArticleNumber.Text(i - ArticleNumberOffset))
    Next

    ' Nieuw MAC adres #1
    For i = MacAddress1Offset To MacAddress1Offset + 16
        newbytes(i) = AscW(NewMac1TextBox.Text(i - MacAddress1Offset))
    Next
    '' Nieuw MAC adres #2
    For i = MacAddress2Offset To MacAddress2Offset + 16
        newbytes(i) = AscW(NewMac2TextBox.Text(i - MacAddress2Offset))
    Next
    ' Nieuw MAC adres #3
    For i = MacAddress3Offset To MacAddress3Offset + 16
        newbytes(i) = AscW(NewMac3TextBox.Text(i - MacAddress3Offset))
    Next
    ' Nieuw MAC adres #4
    For i = MacAddress4Offset To MacAddress4Offset + 16
        newbytes(i) = AscW(NewMac4TextBox.Text(i - MacAddress4Offset))
    Next


    NewCheckSum.Text = Format(Crc32.ComputeChecksum(newbytes), "X")



    Dim FinalBytes() As Byte

    Dim final2bytes(2559) As Byte




    '     MsgBox("7: " + NewCheckSum.Text(5))
    '    MsgBox("6: " + NewCheckSum.Text(4))
    '   MsgBox((Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(5)) + Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(4))))



    '     Dim byte0 = Convert.ToByte(NewCheckSum.Text(6))
    '    Dim byte1
    '   Dim b

    'MsgBox(
    '                    (Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(1)) + Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(0)))
    '       )
    '     (Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(6)) + Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(7))) +
    '    (Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(5)) + Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(4))) +
    '    (Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(3)) + Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(2))) +

    Dim checksumbytes = MyStringConversions.StringToByteArray(NewCheckSum.Text)
    FinalBytes = {&H80, &H8, &H0, &H0,
    checksumbytes(3), checksumbytes(2), checksumbytes(1), checksumbytes(0)
                 }


    Array.ConstrainedCopy(FinalBytes, 0, final2bytes, 0, 8)
    Array.ConstrainedCopy(newbytes, 0, final2bytes, 8, newbytes.Length)




    '        (Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(6)) + Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(7)) - 36),
    ''       (Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(5)) + Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(4)) - 36),
    '    (Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(3)) + Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(2)) - 103),
    '    (Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(1)) + Asc(NewCheckSum.Text(0)) - 103)
    '    }





    Dim fStream4 As New FileStream("" + LocationOfFirmware.FileName.Remove(FirmwareFileLocation.Length - 3) + "_final.dd", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)

    Dim br4 As New BinaryWriter(fStream4)

    br4.Write(final2bytes)
    br4.Close()



    fStream4.Close()

    '  Dim fStream5 As New FileStream(FirmwareFileLocation.Remove(FirmwareFileLocation.Length - 3) + "_tmp_final1.dd", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
    '  Dim br5 As New BinaryWriter(fStream5)
    '  br5.Write(FinalBytes)
    '  br5.Close()
    '  fStream5.Close()


    'Dit hoeft pas wanneer de .dd file een goede serienummer heeft gekregen..
    'Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C" + CopyDataCommandTextbox.Text)
    'Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C" + WriteDataCommandTextbox.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: "Not getting a new file" is not a good explanation. Are you getting an exception? Are you getting a file that is not new? Are you sure the code executes at all? Are you sure where `FirmwareFileLocation.Remove(FileLocation.Length - 3) + "_tmp_final.dd"` ends up pointing to?

Comment: You are correct, it wasn't pointing to the correct location, thank you. However something is still not working propperly, Currently it's creating a file that is only 3 kb. I thought I was reading a file much bigger than this, and editting a 3 kb part of this whole file. Is it possible to read the whole file, editting the 3 kb part with the br4.Write(final2bytes) code and then writing the whole file back to a new location?

Comment: You are using [`FileMode.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which erases the existing file. I believe it would be better if you explained [what you are trying to achieve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640).

Comment: Well I probably have multiple problems, that's why I'm trying to get help from here. I'm currently not really sure what to do anymore. Maybe I should open a filestream to read my current data file, then write it to a new filestream so I can edit it without changing my first file, and after editting I want to save the whole file to a new filename.

After you mentioned the Filemode.create I looked at some things and maybe you were hinting towards FileMode.OpenOrCreate?

Comment: Hi Egbert, Welcome to SO. To get good answers, you would be better including more code .. have a look here to find out more .. [mcve]

Comment: Oh and have a read at the article linked at the bottom of that page - It's extremely helpful.... http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I'm working together with someone else on a project. I updated the first post for more code. Don't mind the mess.

Comment: You probably need a `br4.Flush()` before the close.

Comment: I have added the b44.Flush() right before closing the Filestream, however that didn't make any difference. I still get only 3 kb as output file instead of the 1 GB I am trying to retain.
Thank you for the suggestion though!